# Why won't FormObject execute properly in my notebook?

Tags: input-forms

I want to explore using FormObject and FormFunction.  I copy the most basic example given in the Wolfram Documentation and nothing happens.  Here is a screenshot.

[image]

I've replaced f with a pure function definition and this does not help.  I've tried using FormObject and I get the same output.  I can't get input fields to show up.

Do these commands require a connection to WolframCloud or have some other internet setting that needs to be used?

Comment: Do you have any kind of setting that makes your output in input form rather than standard form? What do you see if you evaluate `1/2`?

Comment: @Kuba That did the trick.  I set the output to StandardForm and it works now.  Thank you!